# Cross platform compilation of C++/Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

I am a C++ novice. I have found an open source project written in C++/Qt.  I want to make slight modifications and compile for both Windows and Mac.  Is it typically that I will need to change my code to support either platform, or can it usually compile for both platforms out of the box?

Comment: Does the project already support both OS? If yes, then no problem. If not, then it depends on the code base, but probably it'd need some adaptation work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source code uses clean C++ and Qt then it should compile (given that you have a Qt project file or Cmake file).  If the code uses any platform specific APIs, you will have to update those first (either with multiple pieces of code, or with other cross-platform APIs)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you don't have to change your code to support both OS s excepting cases described above. You simply have to open folder with ur qt project and open .pro file. The you should compile it and receive ur OS build.